# Two finger rotation using XCUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I have a test case where I have to rotate a map using two finger gestures which I'm attempting to automate. I've tried using the recorder and it only records a tap, not a rotation. Is it possible to simulate a two-finger rotation using the XCUI framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it with the rotate function. Here a docu of a rotate:

```
/*!
     * Sends a rotation gesture with two touches.
     *
     * The system makes a best effort to synthesize the requested rotation and velocity: absolute accuracy is not guaranteed.
     * Some values may not be possible based on the size of the element's frame - these will result in test failures.
     *
     * @param rotation
     * The rotation of the gesture in radians.
     *
     * @param velocity
     * The velocity of the rotation gesture in radians per second.
     */
    public func rotate(rotation: CGFloat, withVelocity velocity: CGFloat)
```

cheers

Comment: This is what I used to rotate